# Role based views in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

I want a particular group of people to access only a particular part of Dashboard. For example,Regional Officers from Northeast should be able to access only the dashboard with Northeast data. Does PowerBI provide this feature?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does; you can view the documentation on it [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-admin-rls/).